# How to define a table view cell in storyboard for use in code?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have a TableViewController on my storyboard that has some cells (static) that I want to add a checkmark to when the cell is tapped, how would I be able to call the individual cells from the storyboard without having to build them in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the delegate of your table view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
     MyCustomCell *cell = [tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];

    // add the checkmark to the cell
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkmarkIcon];
}
```